# HashedWheelTimer in C++?

Tags: c++

Are there any classes that do similar work as `HashedWheelTimer` in Java?

Any classes that support time scheduling and handles will meet our needs. Any suggestion will be great.

Comment: The standard C++ library doesn't have any kind of timers or events. I suggest you start looking through [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/) to see if there is anything you can use there, or do a more thorough Google search.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I am doing Google Searches... but it seems my criteria for the search is bad.. not getting any good results T^T

Comment: Could you describe more that `HashedWheelTimer` class ? It doesn't seem to be a standard java class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the ACE Timer Wheel class [header file](http://www.aoc.nrao.edu/php/tjuerges/ALMA/ACE-5.5.2/html/ace/Timer__Wheel__T_8h-source.html) or one of the ACE Timer Queues.

ACE is available from [here](http://download.dre.vanderbilt.edu/) and has an overview 
[here](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE-overview.html) and relevant documentation [here](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE-documentation.html).

In response to the comment in the question more information regarding HashedWheelTimer and other WheelTimers is available from [here](http://www.cse.wustl.edu/~cdgill/courses/cs6874/TimingWheels.ppt).